# Black screen on login GUI after change username

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed ubuntu 20.04.1 in a virtual machine. I only have one user and after some days of use I decided change the user name. I can change the user name successufully, but after log in with this new user name and I decide close session I'm getting a black screen and I'm unable of do log in again.

This were the commands that I have used to change the username:

```
 # login with root: 
 $ sudo su 
 $ usermod -l newuser -d /home/newuser -m olduser
 # Update the username in the login GUI
 $ sudo usermod -c "MyNew User name" <usermame>
```

The /etc/passwd and etc/group was updated with the new username and also the /home/diruser

What's happening, what I'm doing wrong? I rebooted the system after of change the username and tried again and surprise I can't do login 'a black screen appears'.

[image]

Any Idea for fix this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

when this black screen occurs, you may probably find the error by opening a new term by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and try login with your new username.

if so, check for errors in your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` by running:

```
$ sudo tail -200f /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: Thanks, but that file doesn't exist, proof https://imgur.com/a/6FLd2UZ